# Applet: Exception triggered on close

Tags: java, swing, exception, applet

I having a weird behavior when my applet stops in a webbrowser

```
Exception in thread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-3" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThread)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at sun.applet.AppletSecurity.checkAccess(AppletSecurity.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.checkAccess(Thread.java:1330)
    at java.lang.Thread.interrupt(Thread.java:903)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.interruptIfIdle(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:844)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.interruptIdleWorkers(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:994)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:952)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

can anybody explain this problem ?

Jason

---

while tracking down another bug I got round to simplifying my code to its minimum and in the process located what tirgers this exception:

```
new ImageLoaderWorker(this,background.setCoordinatesCenter(400, 240)).execute();
```

background contains useful information like path dimension etc.

ImageLoaderWorker is as defined:

```
public class ImageLoaderWorker extends SwingWorker<ImageIcon, Void> {

@Override
    public ImageIcon doInBackground() {
        System.err.println("do in background");
        return loadImage();
    }

@Override
    public void done() {
        System.err.println("done");
        try {
            if(!sskkWhitePages.containsKey(iich.getName())){
                sskkWhitePages.put(iich.getName(), get());
            }
            iich.transfertImage();
            if(callback != null){
                callback.imageLoaded(iich.getName());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
        catch (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException e) {
            String why = null;
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause != null) {
                why = cause.getMessage();
            } else {
                why = e.getMessage();
            }
            System.err.println("Error retrieving file: " + why);
        }
    }

/**
     * Load the image for the specified frame of animation. Since
     * this runs as an applet, we use getResourceAsStream for 
     * efficiency and so it'll work in older versions of Java Plug-in.
     */
    protected ImageIcon loadImage() {
        //Not really relevant to the problem I think so I skipped it to avoir overloading the question
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the plugin or security settings. Which browser/OS/Plugin combination are you using?

Comment: in this case I used mac os 10.6 and safari.

Comment: `access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThread)` Why are you attempting to modify threads?  If this is really necessary, use a trusted applet.

Comment: @Andrew: This looks like only VM classes in the stack trace, i.e. nothing Jason did himself.

Comment: I had similar exceptions when I tried to shut down the thread pools I created myself - this might be something like the VM trying to shut down the thread pools at the end. And from the wrong security context.

Comment: I updated my post. I have a gut feeling for some reason these threads are still running in the background and that I should be killing them at one point but I haven't found any information about this in the oracle information.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a JDK bug - see this [NetBeans bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=169770#c9).

The NetBeans bug report cites a JDK bug id and says it is fixed in Java 6.  But the cited JDK bug is no longer accessible.

If your browser has a Java 5 plugin, this is a plausible explanation, and a plausible fix would be to upgrade the plugin to Java 6.